# How to know if a user has stopped their selection in a datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

My scenario: I have a datagridview and it contains some data. User can select a row, or multiple rows in that datagridview, and they need to know a summary about those rows they selected.

Handling multiple rows in datagridview is easy enough, and I have no problem getting what the user need: Two numbers indicate how many item is selected, and their total weight in those rows. I passed that data to a small summary form to display, and I put the code to show that form under `dgv.SelectionChange()`.
But then disaster follow: each time user select a row, that form will appear. Which is, if user select 20 rows, they will see 20 summary forms.... and any more than that, well.. you can imagine. I thought about putting something inside `SelectionChange()` to check if user has stopped their selection.. but can't think of any.

This seems like a very simple matter, but somehow I can't figure it out..
My question, how to know if a user has stopped their selection in a datagridview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you actually have two options.

**Add a button**

Since you can't figure out when the selection is done, just add a button that will call the Form you want to display, that way you are sure that it will display only when user asks for it.

**Use a timer**

Another option is to use a Timer, every time the selection changed, you reset the timer to one second (to keep the example simple). 
And whenever the timer does a tick, you call the Form and stop the timer. That way it will trigger one second (or less) after the user made the selection and gives him one second to change it...

Honnestly, I think the button option is the best, as you give the power to your user. Maybe they will want to select some rows but don't want to see your form, as they will only copy it to paste it somewhere else...

Comment: While a button is all good to go, i'm trying to avoid adding more control into my form as it is already complex for the time being. I'll consider that button when i found out a way to divide up my form while still keeping all of its information intact.

Though, I'll accept your answer due to the timer. That leads me to another solution in which I don't even need to create the summary form: The tooltip. Tooltip has all I need there is, information, timer, and very convenience in my case. I just need to set `toolTip1.InitialDelay = 1500` and it goes perfectly beyond my expectation :D

Comment: @HaPhan OK Let me add that in my answer later today, so it is more accurate and may help other people in the future

Answer (score 1):

I still don't have enough points to just comment, so my answer would be I don't think you can reliably without adding another control (ie, button). You can't read the users mind and since the number of rows can be variable, how would you ever know? You could try something like if the cursor leaves the DGV but that would be frought with issues as well. While it would be an extra click for those just selecting 1 row, I still think having a "Get Summary" button would be the way to go. Sort of like when selecting items to compare - you can click any number of items and while they may show which items you've picked so far in another area, the comparison table doesn't appear until you click the Compare button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While that indeed will solve the problem, I found that I would use a tooltip to display the information instead of popping up a form and all will be good: I only need to set the tooltip initial delay to 1 or 2 sec.
While adding a button is a good way to go, in my case, to be honest I'm trying to avoid adding more control to an already complex form. Maybe I will use this method later if I can think of a way to divide my form to several child forms.